# How can I save the session in nextjs using auth0

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, auth0, next-auth

How can I save my session in next Js using auth0. Every time I refresh the page the session is lost

I only configure auth0 to do Login and Logout, I can get the user information but once I refresh the page it is lost

Answer (score 1):

I use redux for state management and I keep the logged user state by using redux-persist: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist to persist and rehydrate a redux store.

You can create a `store` and a `persistor` and wrap your app with Provider and PersistGate:

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { store, persistor } from "@src/redux/store";

<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={<div>Loading Persistor...</div>} persistor={persistor}>
    {children}
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```