How do I preload session using next auth on my main page in Next14 with App directory?
I have a route '/', where I want to use a hook i.e. useSession() hook in next auth to get the session. But it takes time to fetch the session. So the first render is always without the session and once useSession() hooks gives back the response, it rerenders. So my question is, how can I avoid it so that the first render is already populated with user's session data?
Possible solutions:
I don't want to use Server components, because I'll need some interactivity in my page and afaik server components doesn't provide that.
Showing a loading bar might work but that's still not as good as getServerSideProps in NextJS 12 or before that.
Also, I can't use NextJS's fetch() since I don't have an API to make a call to. I can either use auth from next-auth v5 on server side to get the session OR useSession() on the client side.

Does it answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76498179/12767536?

Server rendering is the only option to do it instantaneously.
Next.JS v14 recommends Server Components Rendering usage for such cases.
Next.JS documentation about Server and Client components: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering.
The idea is to:

load user session data during SSR.
path the loaded data to the client component as the default state:
useClientSession(initialServerSession).

Server components
By default, Next.JS v13+ uses Server Side Rendering (SSR) for React components. It is possible to make server requests inside React functions:
// by default, all components are rendered on the server
export const ParentServerComponent = (props) => {
    //The following call will happen only on the server
    const userSession = getServerSessionFromDbOrMemory();
    
   return <SomeComponents user={userSession} />;
}

React will be rendered on the server side to some form of HTML+JSON and streamed to the client side. A browser will render the prepared HTML+JSON in a fast manner.
Client components
In some cases, you might need browser interaction, for example, updating a state on a click behavior or reacting to a scroll.
For these cases, Next.JS follows the React specification where the line 'use client' at the top of a file makes it a Client Component.
It will be only hydrated on the server but not fully rendered. A browser will download React component JavaScript, parse it, then execute the code, and finally render the component. It is usually much slower than server rendering.
'use client'

export const ClientComponent = (props) => {
   // hooks should be used only inside client components
   const [item, setItem] = useState(0);
   useEffect(() => { }, []);

   return <div>{item}</div>;
}

Mix Server and Client components
It is a good practice to use Server rendering as much as possible and make small Client components.
The loaded server data can be passed to Server components and to Client components, depending on your needs. Also Server components can wrap Client components as in the following example.
export const ParentServerComponent = (props) => {
    //The following call will happen only on the server
    const userSession = getServerSessionFromDbOrMemory();
    
   return <AnotheServerComponent user={userSession}>
      <ClientComponent user={userSession} />
   </AnotheServerComponent>
}

You can also use Client React Provider in the same way and pass the loaded Server data to it.

I'm not sure how to pass initialServerSession to client's session. Could you please share any docs on that? My best bet is to create an endpoint and use NextJS's fetch() to get the data

@TheReBel I added more examples with the documentation link.
